# What is the role of \@typeset@protect in \@setfontsize?

Tags: fonts

The definition of `\@setfontsize` looks like this (output of `\makeatletter\meaning\@setfontsize`)

```
\@nomath#1\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect\let\@currentsize#1\fi\fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont
```

- `\@nomath` issues a warning if you call this macro while in math mode. See source2e.
- `\let\@currentsize#1` is not in my source2e. Mine (v. 2017/01/01 Patch level 1) has `\@currsize#1`
- `\fontsize{fontsize}{baselineskip}`

Revealing `\@typeset@protect` (output of `\makeatletter\meaning\@typeset@protect`) yields `\relax`.

## From source2e.pdf

> To ensure that \@setfontsize keeps
>   being robust we omit this assignment during times where \protect differs from
>   \@typeset@protect.

- When are those times?
- When is this set to something other than `\relax` and for what purpose?
- "keeps being robust" is interesting phrasing by the way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\typeout{\large abc}

\end{document}
```

Produces a log of

```
\relax \fontsize {12}{14}\selectfont abc
```

which isn't particularly interesting but it is code equivalent to `\large` and in real applications where it is writen to `aux` or `toc` files, it works as intended when read back in.

If we modify the definition to remove the `\ifx\protect\@typeset@protect` test then the effect is rather dramatic:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\makeatletter
\def\@setfontsize#1#2#3{\@nomath#1%
%    \ifx\protect\@typeset@protect
      \let\@currsize#1%
%    \fi
    \fontsize{#2}{#3}\selectfont}

\typeout{\large abc}

\end{document}
```

produces

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@nomath ...e \@font@warning {Command \noexpand #1
                                                  invalid in math mode}\fi 
l.13 \typeout{\large abc}

!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

basically the test ensures that font size commands are robust rather than fragile.